# Is it possible to have a function that is in $L^{\infty}(T)$ but not in $L^1(T)$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, matrix-norms

I know that there are functions that exist in the $L^1$ norm but not in the $L^{\infty}$. I'm having trouble coming up with the converse. Could someone provide me an example?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Based on the triple helping of Fourier-based tags, am I right in assuming $T$ refers to the unit circle in $\Bbb{C}$, often denoted $\Bbb{T}$?

Comment: If $T$ indeed denotes the unit circle, this has finite measure, thus any bounded function is integrable.

Comment: Any counterexample will have $T$ being unbounded.

Comment: @Paul Strictly speaking, it's not that the set has to be unbounded but rather that its measure has to be infinite. Some measures give some bounded sets infinite measure. Of course that doesn't happen with Lebesgue measure, but the question makes sense more generally.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is of finite measure $|T|<\infty$, then
$$
\int_T |f| ≤ \|f\|_{L^\infty(T)} \int_T 1 = \|f\|_{L^\infty(T)}\,|T|.
$$
Otherwise, if $|T|=\infty$, the function $f=1$ is a good counterexample since
$$
\|1\|_{L^\infty(T)} = 1 \ \text{ but }\ \|1\|_{L^1(T)} = \int_T 1 = |T| = \infty
$$